# SQL Server leading zeros

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to convert all months to a 2-digit number, from looking like this:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12
```

to this:

```
01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11,12
```

So I put together a simple CASE statement to check if length of month value is = 1, then add a leading zero, otherwise keep as is:

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
       WHEN LEN(MONTH(GETDATE())) = 1 
          THEN RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), MONTH(GETDATE())), 2) 
          ELSE MONTH(GETDATE()) 
    END
```

We are in April and the result of this operation is '4', rather than '04'. When checking the statement (without the conditional statement):

```
right('0' + convert(varchar(2),month(getdate())),2)
```

Then I do get the correct answer ('04')....

This has blown my mind.. I have been at it for a whole day and I cannot figure out why the code alone works, but enveloped in a CASE statement fails.

Please help!

Comment: Still not clear why you would put it in a CASE to begin with I suspect this would be more performant  right('0'+left(month(getdate()),2),2)

Comment: @JohnCappelletti I was going to say the same thing, though I figured the OP would still want to know why it was happening, since it's boggled him so much.

Comment: Tip: `GetDate()` is treated a bit oddly in queries. Each _instance_ will have a constant value within a query. For example `select GetDate() as D1, GetDate() as D2 from SomeTable` may return two different values for the two columns, but they will not vary from one row to the next. When using multiple calls to `GetDate()`, whether in a single statement or multiple statements, one may avoid interesting surprises by getting a single value and using it throughout, i.e. `declare @Now as DateTime = GetDate();` and use `@Now` as needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because your case statement has to return the same datatype, and the else is defaulted to `INT`. It's the order of [precedence](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309(v=sql.110).aspx). Here, you are getting implicit conversion. Casting the `ELSE` would fix this.

```
,CASE 
    WHEN len(month(getdate())) = 1 
        THEN right('0' + convert(varchar(2),month(getdate())),2) 
    ELSE 
        cast(month(getdate()) as varchar(2)) END
```

Comment: Actually is being converted to an int, not varchar because of datatype precedence.

Comment: right @SeanLange i put the wrong thing in there while trying to pull the documentation for precedence, thanks brother!

Comment: My pleasure. The score today is now 1-1. :D

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this by using [FORMAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
SELECT FORMAT(MONTH(GETDATE()), '00')
```

Comment: This assumes they are on 2012+ and while is an alternative, doesn't answer the question. Good alternative though.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a case statement. Below works for all months.

```
select right('0' + convert(varchar(2), month(getdate())), 2)
```

Comment: But this will also add a leading zero with months that have 2-digits, right? i.e. November will be '011'?

Comment: @OdaySalim You could like test.

Answer (score 1):

Convert your ELSE to a varchar(2) and it works fine.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN len(month(getdate())) = 1 
THEN right('0' + convert(varchar(2),month(getdate())),2) 
else CONVERT(varchar(2), month(getdate()))
end
```